# Combine Multiple Actions in jQuery on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to combine multiple actions to the same `on()` function?

My code:

```
$(document).on('mouseout', '#tip', function() {
    $('#tip .ttip').show();
});

$(document).on('click', '#tip', function() {
    $('#tip .ttip').show();
});
```

I have tried the following, but they both did not work.

```
$(document).on('mouseout, click', '#tip', function()
$(document).on({'mouseout', 'click} '#tip', function()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it ..

You need to use a space between the events

```
$(document).on('mouseout click', '#tip', function() {
    $('#tip .ttip').show();
});
```

Although, binding to the `document` is frowned upon. It mimics the [`.live` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which has been deprecated for this reason (*and a few others*).

Quote

> For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of `document` or `document.body` for delegated events on large documents.

---

See the docs at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Quoting

> **on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )**
>   **events** One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "`click`" or "`keydown.myPlugin`".

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery API, 'events' is space separated

> `.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`
>
> `events`: One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as `click` or `keydown.myPlugin`.
>
> `selectorA`: Selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.
>
> `data`: Data to be passed to the handler in event. Data when an event is triggered.
>
> `handler(eventObject)`: A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value false is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return false.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can jus space sparate them like so

```
$(document).on('mouseout click', '#tip', function() {
    $('#tip .ttip').show();
});
```